# What is the best way to set class variable which is an enum based on some conditional logic on a dependent enum in java?

Tags: java, enums, java-8

I am trying to map values from one enum to the other based on some calculation or conditional logic that I need to perform to set the correct enum value for the class variable. How can I do this without using too many if/else, switch statements?

```
Enum BRAND {
 MINI, FERRARI, PAGANI
}
```

and another enum

```
Enum ENGINE {
LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3
}
```

And I have a class like :

```
Class Car() {

 int model;
 int year;
 Engine engine;

 // I want to calculate set the engine depending on the brand based on conditional logic
 public carEngineCalculator (Brand b) {
   Car mycar = new Car();

   if (mycar.isSuperCar(b) {
    if (mycar.isCrazyGood(b)) {
        mycar.engine = ENGINE.LEVEL1;
    } else {
        mycar.engine = ENGINE.LEVEL2;
    }
   } else {
    mycar.engine = ENGINE.LEVEL3;
   }
   ... //And the conditions can be more complex
 }

 public boolean isSuperCar(Brand b) {
    if (b.FERRARI || b.PAGANI) {
     return true;
    } 
    return false;
 }

 public boolean isCrazyGood(Brand b) {
    return ...;
 }
}
```

There can be more than one such conditions that need to be checked in order to set the values and I want to avoid nasty if/else/switch statements as shown above. Is there a more functional way of doing this.

Comment: You're violating naming conventions here. Class names (enums are classes!) should always be in camel case: "Brand" and "Engine". Also I think that "Engine" is not a good name as the enum actualy is not describing whole engines, but a certain classification of engines. Why don't you call it "EngineLevel"?

Also "enuM" and "class" must be lower case, but I guess that's typos.

Comment: @Amadán you are correct.

Comment: The example is too generic to give good answer, but it looks like there is one to one mapping between BRAND enum and ENGINE enum. If that's the case then just have BRAND enum return its specific ENGINE enum.

Comment: You could create a Map with a Predicate as Key and the resulting enum-value as value (or a List of Pairs Predicate/enum-value). Than you can use Java 8-streams to check which of these predicates is the right one and get the wanted enum-value.

Comment: Nice @RalfRenz I like that Idea. Can you provide an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using predicates as I said would look like this:

```
public enum Brand {
    MINI,
    FERRARI,
    PAGANI
}

public enum Engine {
    LEVEL1,
    LEVEL2,
    LEVEL3
}

public class Entry {
    public final Predicate<Car> pred;
    public final Engine engine;

    public Entry(Predicate<Car> pred, Engine engine) {
        this.pred = pred;
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}

public class Car {
    int model;
    int year;
    Engine engine;

    public void carEngineCalculator(Brand b) {
        Car mycar = new Car();

        List<Entry> cases = new ArrayList<>();
        cases.add(new Entry(c -> c.isSuperCar(b) && c.isCrazyGood(b), Engine.LEVEL1));
        cases.add(new Entry(c -> c.isSuperCar(b) && !c.isCrazyGood(b), Engine.LEVEL2));
        cases.add(new Entry(c -> !c.isSuperCar(b), Engine.LEVEL3));

        mycar.engine = cases.stream().filter(x -> x.pred.test(mycar)).findFirst().get().engine;

    }

    public boolean isSuperCar(Brand b) {
        if ((b == Brand.FERRARI) || (b == Brand.PAGANI)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isCrazyGood(Brand b) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You create a List with Predicates and Results and use stream, filter and findFirst to go through the list and find the right result. If the conditions are simpler than you don't need predicates and test it a little bit different.

Answer (score 3):

First, move your `isSuperCar` and `isCrazyGood` methods into `Brand`, rather than have them take a `Brand` parameter. You could similarly add a static factory method to `Engine` that encapsulates the logic you're trying to encode. That doesn't wholly avoid the "nasty if/else/switch statements", but it's likely to be a lot more readable.

For example:

```
public Car(Brand b) {
  this.engine = Engine.forBrand(b);
}
```

and then:

```
enum Engine {
  LEVEL1, LEVEL2, LEVEL3

  public static Engine forBrand(Brand b) {
    if (b.isSuperCar()) {
      return b.isCrazyGood() ? LEVEL1 : LEVEL2;
    }
    return LEVEL3;
  }
}
```

Note also that your `isSuperCar` method can simply be:

```
return b.equals(Brand.FERRARI) || b.equals(Brand.PAGANI);
```

There's never a need to write `if (...) return true; else return false;` or anything similar - just use the boolean expression in the `if` statement directly.

Comment: Ya the if/else was just to demonstrate a simple example, the conditions might not be that simple i.e. might have more than one checks ANDed or ORed together. My Question to you is what if the Engine ENUM is AutoGenerated or part of another library so cant really directly be modified. Should I create a wrapper enum or a helper class to do something similar to what you have suggested?

Comment: Well it's kind of hard to give you a good answer if your actual constraints aren't what you posed in your question. If you can't put the methods on the enum, you'll have to use static utility methods instead (consider an `Engines` class to hold such methods, same for `Brands`, etc.). If you update your question with a more concrete example of the ANDs and ORs you're dealing with I might be able to offer a more helpful suggestion.

Comment: You are right in that there is no reason to write `if (...) return true; else return false;`, still, `return b.FERRARI || b.PAGANI;` is as invalid as the original statement, as `b.FERRARI || b.PAGANI` is not a valid test condition. On the other hand, the question contains more syntax error than correct code. Besides that, I don’t get why you convert one `if` statement to a conditional expression but not the other, i.e. simply use `return b.isSuperCar()? b.isCrazyGood()? LEVEL1: LEVEL2: LEVEL3;`

Comment: Good point, it should presumably be `b.equals(...)`. As to the nested ternary it's just personal style. You certainly *can* nest them, but I don't think it improves the clarity of the code.

Comment: For `enum` constants, you can also use `==`. Regarding nested ternary expressions, they become more readable with an adjusted order, i.e. `!b.isSuperCar()? LEVEL3: b.isCrazyGood()? LEVEL1: LEVEL2`, where conditions are adjacent to their result…

Comment: @Holger to be honest, I find that syntax super opaque. I agree it's concise, but it's not at all readable in my opinion. "Conditions adjacent to their results" breaks down quickly if either the conditions or the results get too long/complex, and even in simple cases it's not obvious what the intent is.

Answer (score 3):

If the mapping is one-to-one for Brand and Engine, you could do something like this:

```
enum Brand {
    MINI(Engine.LEVEL1),
    FERRARI(Engine.LEVEL2),
    PAGANI(Engine.LEVEL3);

    private final Engine engine;

    private Brand(Engine engine) {
        this.engine = engine;
    }

    public final Engine getEngine() {
        return engine;
    }
}
```

Another option:

```
enum Brand {
    MINI(false, false),
    FERRARI(true, true),
    PAGANI(false, true);

    private final boolean superCar;
    private final boolean crazyGood;

    private Brand(boolean superCar, boolean crazyGood) {
        this.superCar = superCar;
        this.crazyGood = crazyGood;
    }

    public final Engine getEngine() {
        if (superCar) {
            return (crazyGood) ? Engine.LEVEL1 : Engine.LEVEL2;
        }
        return Engine.LEVEL3;
    }
}
```

If the mapping is not one-to-one and you need to somehow dynamically calculate the engine based on some parameters, you could also use this:

```
enum Brand {
    MINI {
        @Override
        public Engine getEngine(boolean superCar, boolean crazyGood) {
            return (superCar && crazyGood) ? Engine.LEVEL1 : Engine.LEVEL2;
        }
    },
    FERRARI {
        @Override
        public Engine getEngine(boolean superCar, boolean crazyGood) {
            return superCar ? Engine.LEVEL1 : Engine.LEVEL3;
        }
    },
    PAGANI {
        @Override
        public Engine getEngine(boolean superCar, boolean crazyGood) {
            return Engine.LEVEL3;
        }
    };

    public abstract Engine getEngine(boolean superCar, boolean crazyGood);
}
```

Or something like this, where you have some defaults and override just for special cases:

```
enum Brand {
    MINI,
    FERRARI {
        @Override
        public Engine getEngine(boolean superCar, boolean crazyGood) {
            return superCar ? Engine.LEVEL1 : Engine.LEVEL3;
        }
    },
    PAGANI;

    public Engine getEngine(boolean superCar, boolean crazyGood) {
        return Engine.LEVEL3;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of possibilities using just enums, which I actually prefer to complex if/else or switch statements. Of course it depends on what exactly you want to do and since there is not much info provided, I cannot really give the best answer. Hope that this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably store the brand in the `Car` class, but that is another issue. I would have a static map in the `Car` class that keeps track of which engines go with each brand (as [Ralf Renz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4197431/ralf-renz) suggested):

```
Class Car {

 int model;
 int year;
 Engine engine;
 static Map<Brand, Engine> carEngineMap = new HashMap<>();

 public static void setBrandEngine(Brand b, Engine e) {
   carEngineMap.put(b, e);
 }

 // I want to calculate set the engine depending on the brand based on conditional logic
 public carEngineCalculator (Brand b) {
   Car mycar = new Car();

   mycar.engine = carEngineMap.get(b);
 }

 public boolean isSuperCar(Brand b) {
    if (b.FERRARI || b.PAGANI) {
     return true;
    } 
    return false;
 }

 public boolean isCrazyGood(Brand b) {
    return ...;
 }
}
```

You would then put the conditions in separately for each brand, like

```
Car.setBrandEngine(Brand.FERRARI, Engine.LEVEL2);
Car.setBrandEngine(Brand.PAGANI, Engine.LEVEL1);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

create enum with predicates, CONDITION(brand,  engine, condition) and supply your condition there. Afterwards:

```
Conditions.values().foreach(condition -> {
    condition.isApplicable(variblesDto) ? return condition.apply() : continue;
});
```

and you update your Enum anytime you need new condition. It will also go in order of Enum, so you could play with that